# Rails3 PublicSuffix in application controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I try to employ the `public_suffix` gem to set content of a site based on the top level domain but always get the error `uninitialized constant ApplicationController::PublicSuffix`.

The code of `application_controller.rb`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  helper :all

  before_filter :set_tld

  def set_tld
    servername = request.env['SERVER_NAME']
    tld = PublicSuffix.parse(servername).tld
  end
end
```

I already tried to do a `require 'public_suffix'` inside the function as well as `include PublicSuffix` after `protect_from_forgery` but to no avail.

Comment: I forgot: I added the gem to my Gemfile and bundled and did (some) server restarts

Answer (score 0):

After more than a couple of server restarts my code suddenly works - I don't know how but I guess sometimes miracles happen.

Case closed.